# Form is not centered in iOS7 after keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios7, keyboard

My app works fine in iOS 5 and 6. But in iOS 7 a modal form is not being centered after keyboard is displayed. This doesn't happen with another form in the app, but I am not seeing the difference between them. As you can see in the images below, in the first image it is centered, after keyboard is shown it is move to left side. Any idea? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:
I am using popover to display it:

```
-(IBAction) doSignUp:(id)sender{
    StayInformedVC *vc = [handler getStayInformedVC:self]; //[[StayInformedVC alloc] init];
    popoverStayInformed = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:vc];     
    popoverStayInformed.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [BorderlessPopoverBackgroundView class]; 
    popoverStayInformed.delegate = self; 
    vc.delegate = self;

    float width, height; 

    width = vc.contentSizeForViewInPopover.width;
    height = vc.contentSizeForViewInPopover.height; 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - width/2 , self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 1,1);

    [popoverStayInformed presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    // adds a dim to the background 
    if ( dimViewStayInformed == nil ) {
        dimViewStayInformed = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 
        [dimViewStayInformed setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
        [dimViewStayInformed setAlpha:0.5f]; 

    }

    [self.view addSubview:dimViewStayInformed]; 

}
```

in the stayInformeddVC.m I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popUpView.bounds.size.width, popUpView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some code, specifically the modal presentation/representation code and the view loading code for the modal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution:

I changed this:
`[popoverStayInformed presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

by this:

```
[popoverStayInformed presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```